# How to merge /match two files based on same column in R

Tags: r

I have two file:

1. first file is single column file with header (`file1$sample`), contain 200 samples/line.
2. second is multi column and multiple rows:

   ```
   dim(file2) 
   #[1] 652 20206
   ```

I want to match file1$sample and file2$sample and extract matrix
(200*20206).

I tried following command:

```
new <- merge(file1, file2, by.x='sample', by.y='sample')
```

but is gives only single line file

```
dim(new) 
#[1] 0 20206
```

So please help me how can I extract (200*20206) matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Try `file2[match(file1$sample,file2$sample),]`.

Comment: Thanks nicola, I tried this , it return matrix ( 200 *20206), but all values are "NA"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
file1 = read.table("mydata1.txt", header=TRUE)
file2 = read.table("mydata2.txt", header=TRUE)
m=merge(file1,file2,by="sample")
```

Comment: I tried: file1 = read.table("mydata1.txt", header=T) [1] 200   1,                          file2 = read.table("mydata2.txt", header=T)                                [1]   652 20206 but output is [1]     0 20206

Comment: That code should work. Post an extract of both the files & I shall post the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result=merge(x=file1,y=file2,by="sample",all=T)
```